# Create oracle scheduler job

Tags: oracle, scheduler, jobs, dbms-scheduler

Is there any way to create oracle scheduler job that works (begin and end of some procedure) every day, five times a day at 8,10,12,14,16?

Answer (score 3):

Use this interval definition:

```
'freq=daily;byhour=8,10,12,14,16;byminute=0'
```

So the full code to create the job would be something like:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
        job_name => 'the_job',
        job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action => 'YOUR_PROCEDURE',
        repeat_interval => 'freq=daily;byhour=8,10,12,14,16;byminute=0',
        enabled => TRUE);
```